# How to change color of specific SVG path with CSS only?

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to provide different color to each path. Any suggestion how can I achieve it?

```html
  <svg class="icon-avatar" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M1024 512c0 282.77-229.23 512-512 512s-512-229.23-512-512c0-282.77 229.23-512 512-512s512 229.23 512 512z" fill="rgb(232, 232, 232)"></path>

    <path d="M512 696.32v0c-114.347 0-320 46.080-397.653 137.813 94.618 116.003 237.554 189.485 397.653 189.485s303.036-73.483 396.922-188.56l0.731-0.925c-77.653-91.733-283.307-137.813-397.653-137.813z" 
    fill="rgb(89, 89, 89)">
    </path>

    <path d="M512 573.867c0.254 0.001 0.554 0.002 0.854 0.002 101.177 0 183.225-81.899 183.466-183.019l0-0.023c0.001-0.253 0.002-0.553 0.002-0.853 0-101.561-82.332-183.893-183.893-183.893s-183.893 82.332-183.893 183.893c0 101.411 82.088 183.649 183.442 183.893l0.023 0z" fill="rgb(89, 89, 89)">

    </path
    </svg>
```

Comment: Give each path an Id and select it with that.

Comment: Giving each an ID is best (like @Paulie_D said), but if you can’t, take a look at the [:nth-of-type()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) pseudo-class selector.

Comment: @Noleli can you please elaborate. I am new to svg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the `:nth-of-type()` pseudo-class selector.

```css
.icon-avatar path {
    /* styles that apply to all paths */
}

.icon-avatar path:nth-of-type(1) {
    /* styles for the first path */
}

.icon-avatar path:nth-of-type(2) {
    /* styles for the second path */
}
```